# Effect of 'this' keyword on Arrow and Normal Functions in JavaScript (NodeJS), where the functions are NOT defined in a class/object

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, this

I was recently going learning about the **this** keyword and how it is affected by normal functions *function() {...}* vs arrow functions *()=>{...}*. However, these functions are defined within member functions of a class definition:

```
// Case 1
// filename = index.js

class myClass{
    myString = undefined;
    myNumber = undefined;
    constructor(aString, aNumber){
        this.myString = aString;
        this.myNumber = aNumber;
    }

    logThisWithRegularFunc(){
        let logger = function(){
            console.log(this);  // Console output = undefined, because function(){} created a new scope/definition for 'this'
        }
        return logger();
    }

    logThisWithArrowFunc(){
        let logger = ()=>{
            console.log(this);  // Console output = myClass { myString: [someString], myNumber: [someNumber] }
        }
        return logger();
    }
}
let dumiObj = new myClass("Hello", 200);
dumiObj.logThisWithRegularFunc();
dumiObj.logThisWithArrowFunc();
```

The console output is as expected:

```
$ node index.js
undefined
myClass { myString: 'Hello', myNumber: 200 }
$
```

However, if I create the same two functions **outside** of a class as follows:

```
// Case 2
// filename = index.js

// Regular functions 
function logThisWithRegularFunc(){
    this.someInternalString = "Hello Internal String 1";
    console.log(Object.keys(this));
}

// Arrow Function
let logThisWithArrowFunc = ()=>{
    this.someInternalString = "Hello Internal String 1";
    console.log(Object.keys(this));
}

logThisWithRegularFunc();
logThisWithArrowFunc();
```

I get the following output:

```
$ node index.js
<ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  someInternalString: 'Hello Internal String 1'
}
{ someInternalString: 'Hello Internal String 1' }
$
```

What could be the reason for this? How are the two cases different? How can the behavior of these two functions be justified in these two cases?

*P.S. Thanks in advance! :-)*

Comment: You may want to have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context Also if you called the regular function with `new` keyword like this `new logThisWithRegularFunc();` then you get its own `this scope`

Comment: Also `this` within arrow function refers to global this(or outer this when within another function) . You can verify that by calling `console.log(this)` after `logThisWithArrowFunc();` it will print `{ someInternalString: 'Hello Internal String 1' }` just like it does within the arrow function